# Is there a way to authorize multiple Facebook website URLs?

Tags: facebook, settings

I'd like to authorize both my website URL and http://localhost:12000 so that I can use the SDK both in production and for testing, but when I set the referrer to my production URL and a user tries to login from localhost, I receive an error that this URL isn't authorized.

Is there a way to have multiple URLs authorized simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common way to do this would be to create a test app for your production app in the FB app dashboard.

Select your respective app, and on the left menu you'll see the point "Test Apps". If you create one there, you can specify the redirect url to a different location for testing.

Note:

- You'll have to exchange the app id and app secret in the code you deploy on your test environment to the ones provided for the test app created above